# Как получить объекты из двух вложенных ассоциаций (со скоупом) одним списком?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Есть магазин, у которого много адресов, комментарии(отзывы) пишутся к адресам.

```
@addresses = Address.where(shop_id: @shop.id)
```

Дальше нужно получить все подтвержденные записи. Пытался делать так:

```
@addresses.each do |addr|
      @comments = addr.comments.confirmed
end
```

Но разумеется это срабатывает только для одного последнего адреса.
Пробовал

```
@comments = Comment.new
@addresses.each do |addr|
      @comments = @comments.merge(addr.comments.confirmed)
end
```

Сообщения об ошибках:

`` NoMethodError (undefined method `merge' for#<Comment:0x007ff493627ef8>) ``

`` NoMethodError (undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass) # если @comment = Comment.new ``

**Модель `Comment`**:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  scope :with_text, -> { where.not(:text => nil) }
  scope :confirmed, -> { where(:confirmed => true) }
  scope :starred, -> { where.not(:stars => nil) }

  def confirm!
    self.update_attributes(:confirmed => true)
  end
end
```

Comment: @D-side , у комментариев есть поле confirm: boolean, для подтверждения модераторами

Comment: записывает в @comments все комментарии у которых поле confirm true

Comment: Уберите комментарии, которые уже неактуальны. Модераторы их всё равно увидят, если вас это волнует :) Последняя деталь. У вас в `Shop` есть `has_many :addresses`? Если да, почему не используете, если нет, намеренно ли?

Comment: И правильно ли я понимаю текущий вопрос: **имея магазин, получить все подтверждённые комментарии к его адресам**. Всё так?

Comment: да в модели магазина есть has_many :addresses, возможно просто не понимаю чего-то. Да, задачу можно считать такой

Comment: Просто первая же строка в вопросе, по идее, эквивалентна `@addresses = @shop.addresses`.

Comment: Поэтому я и пишу это в комментарии, а не в ответе :) Вопрос я верно понял? Выше, жирным шрифтом.

Comment: @D-side , да, вопрос понят верно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как правило, если вам нужна коллекция моделей, её лучше получать прямо из базы. То есть, склеивания с помощью Ruby (что вы пытались делать с `merge`) вы делать, как правило, не хотите. Ну и **такого** `merge` действительно не существует.

### Наивный и медленный способ

Если вам надо именно так, то получаемые из базы коллекции можно склеивать между собой **на манер массивов** с помощью оператора `|`, который неявно приведёт коллекцию к массиву и сделает *объединение множеств* элементов этих массивов.

```
@comments = Comment.none # NULL relation, коллекция, не содержащая записей вообще никогда
@addresses.each do |addr|
  @comments |= addr.comments
end
```

**Это устрашающе медленно.** Поэтому вам это сгодится только если **всё совсем плохо** и **альтернатив нет**.

Но **здесь альтернатива есть**.

### Быстрый способ с помощью БД

В основе лежит возможность **соединять** ([термин из реляционной алгебры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5), в SQL просто `JOIN`) таблицы в запросах, чтобы применять условия не только по атрибутам самих записей, но и ассоциированных с ними других записей.

Звучит сложно, **работать с этим просто** (и проблемы с производительностью огребать просто, хотя существенно сложнее, чем если заниматься тем же на стороне Ruby).

Нам надо:

- получить **комментарии**
- отфильтровать по **их же** полю (скоуп)
- под**соединить** к ним их адреса
- а затем отфильтровать **адреса**

И-и:

```
@comments = Comment.confirmed.joins(:address).merge(@shop.addresses)
#                   ^ скоуп   ^ соединение    ^ подмешать  ^ скоуп по другой модели
```

Получится SQL такого рода:

```
SELECT comments.*
FROM comments
  INNER JOIN addresses
          ON addresses.id = comments.address_id
WHERE addresses.shop_id = 16
  AND comments.confirmed
```

- В соединении соединяемые поля выводятся из ассоциации. `Comment` `belongs_to :address` преобразовалось в соединение `comments` с `addresses` по "предикату" (условию) `addresses.id = comments.address_id`
- `merge` позволяет вплющить в один запрос условия аж на разные модели. Но работать это будет только при наличии **соединения**, что здесь и сделано.
- `@shop.addresses` это всего лишь запрос с условием `addresses.shop_id = ?`, как скоуп, просто параметр берётся неявно

Comment: попробовал "быстрый способ", но получаю "TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String)"

Comment: @Tiazar мой косяк, поправил. Метод соединения называется `joins`, не `join`, меня сбивает с толку периодически %)

Comment: Великолепно! отличное решение! Благодарю.